# Questions to ask a 3rd party API provider

Tags: api, documentation, third-party-libraries

I'm due to meet with a developer/sales person from a new 3rd party resource we're about to start using.  The main topic I'll be interested in, is their API as I will be the developer making use of it and explaining it to the rest of the team.

What questions would you recommend asking?

Things I'm already thinking about are:

- What happens and how will I be notified when they depreciate a method?
- Is there ever any downtime?
- Who will I deal with first when I have API issues?

Comment: Your question is too vague. We do not know what matters to you.

Comment: @emddudley I think there are certainly general concerns that all developers will have about an API.

Comment: ask him what the meaning of life is.

Comment: Ask if their source code is in escrow? Think risk mitigation.

Comment: List questions don't make particularly good questions for a Stack Exchange site. Also, the questions that would be most helpful to ask are dependent on your end goals.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the things you suggested by yourself (among which "who will I deal with first when I have API issues" is IMHO the most important question) I would ask

- What kind of documentation do you provide?
- Do you provide samples how to use the API?
- How often do you provide new releases?
- Do you provide a detailed and complete (!) change list for a new release with special hints on breaking changes?
- Do your developers have a test suite in place (for example, to detect breaking changes)? *(if the answer is no or "just for parts", you may consider bringing your own test suite in place)*
- Which requirements for the OS environment or run time environment does the lib have? What happens if there is a new version of the OS / run time environment, how quick can you test the lib / provide a new version if necessary?
- What requirements on resources (memory, network, file system space, processor speed etc.) does the lib have?

Answer (score 1):

Though there is a laundry list of potential questions, the answer to your question is simply:

**Read the API documentation before the initial meeting on the API and ask for any additional information that you will need for the success of the project.**